# How to get the highest value from a child association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an order model that has_many items.

**`app/models/order.rb`**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  before_save :set_status

  enum item_status: [:one, :two, :three]

  private
    def set_status
      self.items.each do |i|
        self.item_status = i.item_status if i.item_staus > self.item_status
      end
    end
end
```

Both models have the same "item_status" enum and attribute.

I think the comparison is not working because it is not comparing the actual INT value but rather the enum string value.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `maximum` to perform the query in the database, using the stored integer value rather than the `ActiveRecord`-wrapped records where you're performing your comparisons agains the symbols:

```
def set_status
  self.item_status = self.items.maximum(:item_status)
end
```